# How to boost search results in haystack with elasticsearch?

Tags: django, search, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am using elasticsearch with haystack. I would like to have search results for user profile in following way:

When you search for "abc" you should get results that have "abc" in them. Nothing else. You first look at the first_name and last_name, then everything else. So the first results will be about people who have "abc" in their name, then "abc" in their profile.

Also when you search for "abc xyz", you should first get results with "abc xyz" (first for first_name and last_name then for everything else), and then results that have either "abc" or "xyz" in them (first for first name and last_name then for everything else).

I thought boosting will help in order to achieve this and so I have tried to provide boost value at field level as following, but it didn't change results.

```
class ProfileIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
    first_name = indexes.CharField(null=True, boost=1.5)
    last_name = indexes.CharField(null=True, boost=1.125)
    valid = indexes.CharField(default=True)
    other_fields = ....
```

I am performing search using autocomplete. E.g.

```
results = SearchQuerySet().models(Profile).filter(SQ(valid="yes")).autocomplete(content=search_keyword.lower())
```

And following is template for document field:

```
{{ object.user.first_name }}
{{ object.user.last_name }}
{{ object.title }}
.....
.....
```

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve above ?

Thanks.